# USB Charger (Samsung/Apple/Dedicated)

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, apple

I have read a lot of lines about D+/D- Voltage when using different devices. Also the Article from maxim integrated. The conclusion is:

[image: Voltage on D+/D- for USB Charging]

I test it with iPhone X(iOS 15.6.1) and i found something interesting:

- D+/D- open floating charging the phone takes 1A
- D+/D- connected   floating   the phone takes 1A
- D+/D- 1.2V (Samsung)         the phone takes 1A
- D+ 2.7V / D- 2.0V (Apple)     the phone takes 1A

I don't understand it.  Could somebody explain please?

Comment: What you don't understand and what do you need explained?

Comment: ... sorry. When i read the instruction then i expect differnt loading current.
open 0.1A ; connected 0.5A; 1.2V ???; 2.7/2.0V 2A

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get? I can't understand what scenario the question is about and what the question is.